# Accessing Couchbase Transaction response outside lambda

Tags: java, reactive-programming, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to use java sdk (java-client v3.4.3).
Since I need transactions, I am using transactional flavor of cluster object

```
cluster.reactive().transactions().run((ctx) -> {});
```

Both sync/ async versions expect lambda and return

> TransactionResult /
> Mono < TransactionResult >

Since java requires that in a lambda,  local variables be final or effectively final, how am I supposed to share the response of say ctx.insert() or ctx.replace() outside this transaction? I want to access the cas value for ctx.insert but I am not able to send data out of this transactions().run() function.

Using global variables does not appear the right choice to me.

Comment: For anyone else who comes along, it looks like this was cross-posted to Couchbase Forum and answered there https://forums.couchbase.com/t/java-sdk-reactive-transactions-responses/35740